# Mapped Value Not Becoming Observable, etc

Tags: knockout.js

```
var modules;

$.when(
    $.get('modules.json', function(data) {
        var mapping = { 'observe' : ['enabled'] };
        modules = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
    })
).then(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(modules));
});

function viewModel(modules) {

    var self = this;

    self.modules = modules;

    console.log(self.modules());

    ...

}
```

Shouldn't the `enabled` key value in each module object from the json array show up as an observable function in my console with a value set to what was defined in the json (in this case `true`)?

Also, what's a better way of waiting to bind the received json data than the way I am trying now (if there is a better way)?

An object from my json array looks like this:

```
{
    "id" : "spnsrlogo",
    "name" : "Sponsor Logo",
    "code" : "<h3>Sponsor Logo</h3><label for=\"spnsrLogoSrc\" data-bind=\"text: $root.spnsrLogoSrc\">Sponsor Logo Path</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"spnsrLogoSrc\" data-bind=\"value: $root.spnsrLogoSrc, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'\">",
    "output" : "assets/img/sponsor-logo.png",
    "enabled" : true
}
```

Also, how can I utilize the `code` value so that when it is appended the observables become active? See this non-working attempt as an example:

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: modules">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.modulesEnabled(), value: $data.id, attr: { id: $data.id }">
        <label data-bind="attr: { for: $data.id }, text: $data.name" class="inlineblock"></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modulecontainer" data-bind="foreach: modules">
    <div class="moduleoptions" data-bind="visible: $parent.modulesEnabled(), html: code, attr: { id: 'module-' + $data.id}"></div>
</div>
```

I tried making modulesEnabled an observable array but that didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I finally managed to get things working. I want to thank pax162 for his second answer because without it I would have been lost.

I ended up structuring my JSON like so:

```
{
    "id" : "isi",
    "name" : "ISI",
    "code" : "<h3>ISI</h3><label for=\"isiHeading\">ISI Heading</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"isiHeading\" data-bind=\"value: isiHeading, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'\"><label for=\"isiContent\">ISI Content</label><textarea id=\"isiContent\" data-bind=\"value: isiContent, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'\"></textarea><label for=\"isiFooter\">ISI Footer HTML</label><textarea id=\"isiFooter\" data-bind=\"value: isiFooter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'\"></textarea>",
    "observables" : ["isiHeading","isiContent","isiFooter"]
}
```

And then with a bit of deferred jQuery magic and manually adding my observables:

```
$.when(
    $.get(options.paths.modules, function(data) {
        self.modules = data;
        for (var i=0, l=self.modules.length; i<l; i++) {
            if (typeof(data[i].observables) !== "undefined") {
                for (var j=0, ll=data[i].observables.length; j<ll; j++) {
                    self.modules[i][data[i].observables[j]] = ko.observable('');
                }
            }
            self.modules[i].enabled = ko.observable(true);
        }
    })
).then(function() {
    self.successful();
    ko.applyBindings(self);
}, function(o) {
    console.log(o);
});
```

And if anyone is curious, my successful function contains the customHtml binding handler definition and creation of other more general observables that I am using elsewhere (that don't depend on the JSON received):

```
this.successful = function() {

    ko.bindingHandlers.customHtml = {
        init: function(element,valueAccessor,allBindings,viewModel,bindingContext) {
            $(element).html(valueAccessor());
            ko.applyBindingsToNode($(element)[0],{with:viewModel}, bindingContext.$root);
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        },
        update: function(element,valueAccessor,allBindings,viewModel,bindingContext) {
            //
        }
    };

    // other functionality not relevant to this problem

};
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the question, I had a look through the mapping source. Somewhere around [here](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/knockout.mapping.js#L472), the observe setting is processed. It works by matching the "full path" of a property with exactly the strings you passed in the observe array.

With your json hierarchy, the enabled properties should be specified as [0].enabled, [1].enabled, [2].enabled and so on. At the moment I think you have to pass them exactly like this in the array, maybe we should ask one of the plugin maintainers if it can be changed into something like [i].enabled, to take into account all members of the array. If any of the maintainers / hardcore_users reads this: Guys, am I correct?

So you'll have to generate the 'observe' config array to be as long as the number of items you have in the initial data, to look like this:

```
var mapping = { 'observe' : ['[0].enabled', '[1].enabled', '[2].enabled',.../*and so on*/ ] };
```

It would probably be nicer to change your json structure.

For the second part of the question, it can be done with a custom binding, like this one:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customHtml = {
    init:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){  
        $(element).html(valueAccessor());
        ko.applyBindingsToNode($(element).find("div")[0],{with:viewModel}, bindingContext.$root );        
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };              
    },
    update:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){                               
    }
}
```

Note that I added some div tags to wrap the html in the code properties.

The initial html in the page changes like this, I only added the customHtml customBinding:

```
<div id="modulecontainer" data-bind="foreach: modules">
    <div class="moduleoptions" data-bind="visible: $parent.modulesEnabled(), customHtml: code, attr: { id: 'module-' + $data.id}"></div>
</div>
```

And finally, the fiddle with all code: http://jsfiddle.net/cUVN8/3/